# Recolectar datos de input json y guardar en db con Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estaba necesitado autogenerar inputs dinamicamente y me encontré con este tutorial que me pareció simple y funciona bien.
https://smarttutorials.net/dynamically-add-or-remove-input-textbox-using-vuejs/

El problema es que necesito guardar los datos en la base de datos y tengo varias trabas.

La primera es que uso la ultima versión de xampp con phpmyadmin y no encuentro el tipo de dato json. Sé que está integrado ese tipo de dato en las nuevas versiones. No sé por que no aparece en la mia.

Igualmente buscando en google encontré que se puede usar longtext en su reemplazo pero me da error.

Si son tan amables me pueden indicar si lo estoy trabajando bien o me falta modificar algo.

Migración

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('mails', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('usuario_id')->unsigned();
            $table->longtext('mails');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('usuario_id')->references('id')->on('usuarios')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Vista inputs

```
<form method="post" v-on:submit.prevent="EnviarEmails">
                  <!-- Heading -->
                  <h3 class="dark-grey-text text-center mt-4">
                    <strong>Cuentas:</strong>
                  </h3>
                  <hr>
                  <div class="form-group" v-for="(input,k) in inputs" :key="k">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="input.name">
                      <span>
                          <i class="fas fa-minus-circle" @click="remove(k)" v-show="k || ( !k && inputs.length > 1)"></i>
                          <i class="fas fa-plus-circle" @click="add(k)" v-show="k == inputs.length-1"></i>
                      </span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-indigo">Enviar</button>
                    {{-- <button class="btn btn-indigo" @click="EnviarEmails">Enviar</button> --}}
                    <hr>
                  </div>
```

Métodos vue

```
add: function(index) {
            this.inputs.push({ name: '' });
        },
        remove: function(index) {
            this.inputs.splice(index, 1);
        },

        EnviarEmails: function(){
            var url = '/mailsEnviados';
            axios.post(url, {my_prop_name :JSON.stringify(this.inputs)
                }).then(response => {
                }).catch(error => {

            });
          },
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // foreach(json_decode($request->input('my_prop_name ')) as $my_object_in_array)
        // {
        //  print_r($my_object_in_array);
        // }
        $mails = new Mails();
        $mails->usuario_id = 1;
        $mails->mails = $request->all();
        $mails->save();
        return true;
    }
```

La vista donde mostrar los datos

```
@foreach($datos as $usuario)

                    <tr>
                      <td>{{$i++}}</td>
                      <td>{{ $usuario->usuario_id }}</td>
                      <td>{{ json_decode($usuario->mails) }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $usuario->created_at}}</td>


                    </tr>

                    @endforeach
```

Agradezco mucho su tiempo invertido en mi consulta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

`$request->all()` te arroja un array con todos los elementos del request, si deseas que vaya completa deberas guardarla como

```
json_encode($request->all());
```

Por otra parte te recomiendo que utilices las propiedades en el modelo Mails para trabajar siempre con arrays y no tengas que convertir a JSON

```
protected $casts = [
    'mails' => 'array',
];
```

Tambien veo que no estas utilizando el csrf_token asi que te recomiendo revisarlo.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias. Agregue todas tus sugerencias y se guarda en la tabla. El formato es así: {"my_prop_name":"[{\"cuenta\":\"hola\"},{\"cuenta\":\"chau\"}]"} está bien que sea así? como puedo mostrar en la vista estos datos? necesito sólo agregar el contenido de cada cuenta. Me puedes brindar una mano más con eso?

Comment: Coloca tu código donde lo vas a mostrar para poder ayudarte

Comment: Edite la pregunta y al final agregue la vista. Te agradezco mucho tu dedicación.